# javascript - prevent checkboxes from becoming both checked AND disabled

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox, selectors-api

I have a program where javascript changes several checkboxes, making them, disabled, checked, or unchecked based on what other boxes are checked.  I've noticed that if you have a checked checkbox and then you make it disabled, it can be both checked and disabled at the same time.  I don't want this to ever be possible. I want any checkbox that becomes disabled, to also become unchecked.  I was looking for an easy way to do it.  I thought queryselectorall would work.  Here's a simplified example.  In this example, I made one of the boxes checked AND disabled by default.  If you click another box, it should get rid of the check in the disabled box.  I thought this simple function would do that, but it doesn't work.

```js
 function fixit() {
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked:disabled').checked=0;
    }
```

```html
    <form id='theform' name='mainform' method='post' action='#'>
    box1<input onClick='fixit()' type='checkbox' disabled checked> 
    box2<input onClick='fixit()' type='checkbox'>
    box3<input onClick='fixit()' type='checkbox'>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns an element list, which does not have a property `checked`. You need to iterate over the list of elements and apply your change.

```js
function fixit() {
  var cbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked:disabled');
  for(var i = 0;i<cbs.length;i++){
    cbs[i].checked = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id='theform' name='mainform' method='post' action='#'>
    box1<input onClick='fixit()' type='checkbox' disabled checked> 
    box2<input onClick='fixit()' type='checkbox'>
    box3<input onClick='fixit()' type='checkbox'>
    </form>
```

Comment: Ahhh !  that's what I needed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HTML DOM removeAttribute() Method.

```js
function fixit() {
  var i, cb = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked:disabled');
  for (i = 0; i < cb.length; i++) {
    cb[i].removeAttribute("checked");
  }
}
```

```html
<form id='theform' name='mainform' method='post' action='#'>
  box1
  <input onClick='fixit()' type='checkbox' disabled checked>box2
  <input onClick='fixit()' type='checkbox'>box3
  <input onClick='fixit()' type='checkbox'>
</form>
```

Edit: I forgot to loop through the returned checkboxes array.

Comment: Another nice answer.  thank you.  There's a few different answers that all work.  very good !

Answer (score 1):

```js
function fixit() {
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked:disabled').forEach(function(x) {
x.checked = 0;
});

}
```

```html
<form id='theform' name='mainform' method='post' action='#'>
    box1<input onClick='fixit()' type='checkbox' disabled checked> 
    box2<input onClick='fixit()' type='checkbox'>
    box3<input onClick='fixit()' type='checkbox'>
    </form>
```

Comment: I already selected a correct answer, but this works too.  very nice.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use external JavaScript, putting the `<script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>` in your `<head>`

**external.js**

```
var pre = onload, doc, bod, htm, E, fixIt;
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre();

doc = document, bod = doc.body;
E = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
fixIt = function(formElement){
  var es = formElement.elements;
  for(var i=0,e,l=es.length; i<l; i++){
    e = es[i];
    if(e.disabled && e.checked){
      e.checked = false;
    }
  }
}
fixIt(E('theform')); // use whenever

}
```